# What part of this argument is circular?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

"If we are to define the real numbers from the Cauchy sequences of rationals as limits of Cauchy sequences, we have to know when two Cauchy sequences of rationals give the same limit, without first defining a real number(since that would be circular)."

this paragraph is from the Tao's analysis 1 book 100p.

you can check the whole contents in this link.
https://lms.umb.sk/pluginfile.php/111477/mod_page/content/5/TerenceTao_Analysis.I.Third.Edition.pdf

my concern is that I can’t understand what argument would be circular.

a circular argument would be like this.

“why is A?” “because B” “then why is B?” “because A”

but I can’t find what argument would be circular in this 100p paragraph.

please help.

Comment: If you try to use sequences to define the reals, but you use reals to define when two sequences have the same limit, then you are using the reals to define the reals.

Comment: A circular definition uses slightly different words than a circular proof: “what is A?” “something that involves B” “then what is B?” “something that involves A”

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The argument is something like this:

1. Take the set of all possible Cauchy sequences of rational numbers, call it $C(\mathbb{Q})$.
2. Define the equivalence relation $(a_n) R (b_n)$ when $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n$.
3. Define the set $\mathbb{R}$ as being the set of all equivalence classes of $R$ in $C(\mathbb{Q})$.

The problem is in step 2 - if the real numbers don't exist yet, then any Cauchy sequence that doesn't converge to a rational number effectively doesn't have a limit.

That's why you need some other way of saying "these two Cauchy sequences converge to the same value" so that you can then call that value a real number.